# Change the position of the Errors cakephp

Tags: cakephp, position

I need to change the position of all the errors, not the flash-messages!
I cant find the location where the error is going into the view, I searched for hours in CakePHP, and can not find the right answer on internet!

Pleas help me

Comment: Introducing new acronym - WHYT - What Have You Tried?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I have tried to find the place where the error in the default view comes.
I know that in the Debugger.php the error is created, but i can't find where the error the default view in comes!

Comment: What type of error are you referring if not the flash messages? Have you tried looking in the layouts?

Comment: thanks for the repley! i have tried that, there you only can change the flash message. not the error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwrite with css id="flashMessages" class="message"